# Prevent "Search Google" to be selected in address bar

Tags: macos, mac, safari

If I open Safari on my Mac and type `foo` in the address bar, it will be

> foo — Search Google

This is fine, but if I need to copy this text, I press Command-A and then Command-C, and this selects the *entire* text in address bar, that is, including the "em dash Search Google" part.

Is there a way to prevent it, so that Command-A will select only the text I have actually typed there (that is, `foo`)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To copy addressbar content only:

- CMD+L to select addressbar content,
- CMD+C to copy and
- CMD+V to paste

Comment: Sorry, I need to edit the question. Wait a minute...